# How do I dynamically (AJAX) show radios in form API?

Tags: forms, ajax, 9

A form like the following is expected to show additional fields when user selected "Yes" in the "Show more" radio button. When shown, the more section has a "Name" text field, and a "Gender" radios set.

But it never works as expected. The "Gender" label will be there, but the radio buttons are never rendered. I know changing "Gender" into radios would work, but for some reason, I need to use multiple radio buttons. Is there any way I can make this work?

```php
<?php

namespace Drupal\mymodule\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;

class DonationPrepareForm extends FormBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getFormId() {
    return 'my_form';
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function buildForm(
    array $form,
    FormStateInterface $form_state
  ) {
    $form['show_more'] = [
      '#type' => 'radios',
      '#title' => 'Show more',
      '#options' => [
        'Y' => 'Yes',
        'N' => 'No',
      ],
      '#ajax' => [
        'callback' => '::ajaxBuildForm',
        'wrapper' => 'edit-more-wrapper',
        'progress' => [
          'type' => 'throbber',
          'message' => $this->t('Loading...'),
        ],
      ],
    ];
    $form['more'] = [
      '#type' => 'container',
      '#prefix' => '<div id="edit-more-wrapper">',
      '#suffix' => '</div>',
    ];

    return $form;
  }

  public function ajaxBuildForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state)
  {
    if ($form_state->getValue('show_more') === 'Y') {
      $form['more']['name'] = [
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => 'Name',
        '#required' => TRUE,
      ];
      $form['more']['gender'] = [
        '#type' => 'radios',
        '#title' => 'Gender',
        '#options' => [
          'M' => 'Male',
          'F' => 'Female',
        ],
        '#required' => TRUE,
      ];
    }
    return $form['more'];
  }
}
```

Same question extends to other composite form elements (e.g. Checkboxes). Is there any way to make AJAX work for them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move form building to buildForm(). You can't build form elements in an Ajax callback (I've also renamed the callback method to make this clear):

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\mymodule\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;

class DonationPrepareForm extends FormBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getFormId() {
    return 'my_form';
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
     $form['show_more'] = [
      '#type' => 'radios',
      '#title' => 'Show more',
      '#options' => [
        'Y' => 'Yes',
        'N' => 'No',
      ],
      '#ajax' => [
        'callback' => '::ajaxCallback',
        'wrapper' => 'edit-more-wrapper',
        'progress' => [
          'type' => 'throbber',
          'message' => $this->t('Loading...'),
        ],
      ],
    ];
    $form['more'] = [
      '#type' => 'container',
      '#prefix' => '<div id="edit-more-wrapper">',
      '#suffix' => '</div>',
    ];

    if ($form_state->getValue('show_more') === 'Y') {
      $form['more']['name'] = [
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => 'Name',
        '#required' => TRUE,
      ];
      $form['more']['gender'] = [
        '#type' => 'radios',
        '#title' => 'Gender',
        '#options' => [
          'M' => 'Male',
          'F' => 'Female',
        ],
        '#required' => TRUE,
      ];
    }

    return $form;
  }

  public function ajaxCallback(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    return $form['more'];
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works!

Answer (score 2):

Actually it is significantly easier to use form element #states property to make an element visible , invisible , enabled , disabled , required or ... rather than using ajax

A code like this will do the job:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\mymodule\Form;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormBase;

class DonationPrepareForm extends FormBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function getFormId() {
    return 'my_form';
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function buildForm(
    array $form,
    FormStateInterface $form_state
  ) {
    $form['show_more'] = [
      '#type' => 'radios',
      '#title' => 'Show more',
      '#options' => [
        'Y' => 'Yes',
        'N' => 'No',
      ],
    ];


    $form['more']['name'] = [
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => 'Name',
      '#states' => array(
        'visible' => array(
          ':input[name="show_more"]' => array('value' => 'Y'),
        ),
        'required' => array(
          ':input[name="show_more"]' => array('value' => 'Y'),
        )
      ),
    ];
    $form['more']['gender'] = [
      '#type' => 'radios',
      '#title' => 'Gender',
      '#options' => [
        'M' => 'Male',
        'F' => 'Female',
      ],
      '#states' => array(
        'visible' => array(
          ':input[name="show_more"]' => array('value' => 'Y'),
        ),
        'required' => array(
          ':input[name="show_more"]' => array('value' => 'Y'),
        )
      ),
    ];

    return $form;
  }
```

}

Comment: This does not work for my case because I'd want the appeared fields to be required fields.

Comment: What does this not work exactly? The required state is also input-dependent in the answer?

Comment: States don't work for radio buttons: https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3267246